# How to upload key card to iOS app and allow students to use it to unlock RFID enabled doors

Tags: iphone, security, nfc, rfid

iOS 13 is adding some new NFC stuff (this might already be possible with iOS 12 but idk) and I was wondering if this was possible/how to go about it.

I maintain an app that I developed for my high school. My school uses HID Proximity cards (RFID) which students use to get into the building. These suck because people don't bring wallets to school and if you get there late you have to spend forever looking for your card.

I want to add the ability to use your iPhones NFC capabilities to unlock the door. I have a working key that I want to clone, and I want to create a feature that lets students open the door using their phone. Don't worry about security, I have the ability to authenticate that students actually go to the school. How would I go about uploading my keycard to the app, and making my phone able to emulate it?

Comment: I'm not convinced with the first answer, I (like many other developers I'm sure) are thinking about exactly the same thing. How can I ditch my office door card and open doors with my iPhone.
@Skyler Wiernik have you found additional info about this?

Comment: I've given up since then. If its possible, someone will publish something open source eventually. But if I see anything, I'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't support HCE (host card emulation) for the moment.

They planned it was reported.

https://www.quora.com/When-will-NFC-card-emulation-be-available-in-iOS

https://9to5mac.com/2018/05/25/apple-will-reportedly-open-up-nfc-in-ios-12/